# Automatically enter a pw for a bit bucket account?

Tags: password, git

I have a git repo on an ubuntu 12.04 machine synced with a remote bit bucket repo. When I do a git pull I have to always provide a password. Is there a way to store that PW so that I don't have to enter it each time I do a pull?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very detailed guide [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678).

In short, you need to

1. generate a key pair (check if `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` exists)
2. add that public key into Bitbucket>Manage account>Security>SSH Keys>Add Key .
3. Then you should edit the `.git/config` file in your project folder, change the https url to ssh format.

   ```
   from: https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
   to:   ssh://git@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
   ```

Comment: It would be better to use `git remote set-url` instead of editing `.git/config`.